# Backbone.js IE8 not styling HTML5 tagNames

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I'm having issues with IE8 not styling certain HTML5 elements with Backbone.js (0.9.1); the issue only arrises when using an HTML5 tagName for a View, and then appending the view's element.

I'm using modernizr and have the appropriate display:block css, and I can add other HTML5 elements using jQuery's html(), append(), etc, so this makes me think it is a Backbone  specific issue.

At this point I'm debating between working around this and just never using HTML5 tagNames, or no longer using Backbone, neither of which is ideal. Any suggestions?

Here's the simplest example of the issue:

```
$(function(){
    var test = Backbone.View.extend({ tagName: 'section' });

    var section = new(test);

    $('body').append(section.el);
});
```

Edit:

For some reason rolling back from Modernizr 2.5 to 2.0 fixed the issue for Views with HTML5 tagNames, but now I have to use innerShiv when appending template content into elements. Not sure why it didn't like 2.5, but it works for now.

Going to look into it further and see if I can narrow down why this is happening, and see if a better solution can be found.

Comment: Generally, if you have some "unsolvable" issue with Backbone.js, the best thing you can do is looking directly into its source code, it's quite easy to understand.

Comment: That wouldn't necessarily be Backbone; that would more likely be your templating engine (I wouldn't swear it is, though).

Comment: I checked the source. Its something to do with how Backbone creates elements outside of the DOM using document.createElement(tagName). The issue occurs without any templating involved, so I'm not sure how that could be the problem.

Here's the simplest example of the issue:
`$(function(){
 var section = new(test);
 $('body').append(section.el);
});

var test = Backbone.View.extend({
 tagName: 'section'
});`


The section tag is removed and shows as <:section> in IE; and not styled properly.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with using tag names that aren't standard in non-modern browser (I'm looking at you, IE), you must use declare your own namespace and use your "custom" tag along with your namespace.

> Windows Internet Explorer's support for custom tags on an HTML page
>   requires that a namespace be defined for the tag. Otherwise, the
>   custom tag is treated as an unknown tag when the document is parsed.

You can find the source article here in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531076%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Of course, declaring your own namespace is already non-trivial when it comes to writing html. In fact, it's unheard-of before I encounter this same problem. Needless to say, the implications is that you'd have tags that look like `<namespace:section>`.

Your solution would be to either stay away from the new and fancy HTML5 html tags if you are to support IE8, or you should customize your code to use different tag for IE8.

An alternate solution which I remember reading was to use classes with the same name as the new tags you intend to employ. For example, treat `<div class="section">` the same as you would treat `<section>`.